# htaccess exclude directories recercively (sugarcrm & mvc)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a copy of codeigniter running. And I am now also attempting to install a CRM sugrar crm to be exact in a sub directory. and none of the stylesheets, images, other are loading because CI is overridding the way sugarcrm wrote there system and how they included things like CSS and JavaScript into it.

My current htaccess rule looks like:

```
#remove index from url
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|crm|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

which works generally if files are included something like ./file/path/ but in this case I am trying to ignore the crm directory as you can see. But it doesn't seem to be recursive down the line.

sugarcrm includes there files like `src="css/something"` if they had did it `src="/css/something"` i dont think this would be a problem. But Im trying to sort this out and I dunno which direction to take this in, ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line are your exceptions

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|crm|robots\.txt)
```

so if you want to add 'css' folder to exceptions

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|crm|css|robots\.txt)
```

if that fails try searching other probable issues like [this](http://cheleguanaco.blogspot.pt/2011/05/sugarcrm-troubleshooting-formatting.html)

Comment: I understand that, thats why I have that line. However it seems that subdirectories in the crm directory are not being carried over in the rule.. Example SugarCRM creates a cache for static files, and automatically calls on them if they are there. So seems when SugarCRM calls a src like `cache/css/cssfile.css` the MVC I have caches it and throws it back as a 404 cause it then treats /crm/cache/.... like its part of the MVC despit the condition given above to exclude crm

Comment: You sure is htaccess problem? Have you tried without it and works?

Comment: I'm pretty sure rewrite exceptions extend to subdirectories, see if [this](http://cheleguanaco.blogspot.pt/2011/05/sugarcrm-troubleshooting-formatting.html) isn't your issue

Comment: nope, didnt think that simple lol, but removing htaccess from the equasion, shows it as not working

Comment: Edit your answer to show the link that you provided in the comment, and I will check this answer as the one, seeing as that link solved the problem